# Search particular string in entire html using Beautiful Soup in Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I would like to search for particular string in scraped html page and perform some action if string is present.

```
find = soup.find('word')
print(find)
```

But this gives `None` even there is `word` in page. Also, I tried:

```
find = soup.find_all('word')
print(find)
```

And it gives `[]` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `find = soup.findAll(text="word")`

Comment: This is woking fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What `find` method does is searching for a tag. So when you do `soup.find('word')` you're asking BeautifulSoup to find all the `<word></word>` tags. I think it's not what you want.

There are several ways to perform what you're asking. You can use `re` module for searching with a regular expression like that:

```
import re

is_present = bool(re.search('word', response.text))
```

But you can avoid importing extra modules, as you use Scrapy, which has a built-in methods for working with regular expressions. Just use `re` method on selector:

```
is_present = bool(response.xpath('//body').re('word'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Stas, **find = bool(re.search('word', content))** gives me **"source.tell() - here + len(this))
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0"** and **find = bool(content.xpath('//body').re(content))** gives "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'xpath'". Here, content is the response.body I am passing to parser. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: **find = bool(content.xpath('//body').re('word'))**

Comment: If you use Scrapy, you should have a `Response` object, which is passed to your callback function as a first argument.

Comment: Yes @Statas, I am passing in callback function as response.body and getting it as content in calling function.

Comment: Okay, try this then: `is_present = bool(re.search('word', str(content)))`

Comment: I am getting  `source.tell() - here + len(this)) sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position `